# mysql SELECT from two tables with two statements

Tags: mysql

I have two tables in mysql:

`tbl_users` and `tbl_products`

`tbl_users = userID, userEmail, userPassword`

`tbl_products = creatorID, serialNumber, artNumber, regDate`

I need to select two rows: one from `tbl_users` and one from `tbl_products` where serial number = ??? and userID = ???.

When I use

```
SELECT * 
FROM   tbl_users, 
       tbl_products 
WHERE  userid = 8 
       AND serialnumber = 23432535
```

I got 0 results (because number in serialNumber is fake).

But when I use

```
SELECT * 
FROM   tbl_users, 
       tbl_products 
WHERE  ( userid = 8 
         AND serialnumber = 23432535 ) 
        OR userid = 8
```

In result I got way more than one row. I don't know why because serialNumber is fake and only one user have id=8.

Can some one explain why I got more than one row in the result set? Thanks

**@edit**

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl_users 
WHERE userID=8 
UNION 
SELECT creatorID,serialNumber,artNumber 
FROM tbl_products 
WHERE serialNumber=23432535
```

`UNION` solve my problem. Thanks

Comment: Promote the use of  explict `JOIN` sintaxis, Aaron Bertrand wrote a nice article [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) about it.

Comment: Use http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm to format the SQL code and use control-k to format the text as code.

Answer (score 1):

thats because you are missing the clause for the relation between the tables, I guess in your example would be

```
and creatorID = userID
```

Comment: I still have 5 results because this user have 5 products but he dont have product with serial number = 23432535. I don't know if what im try to do is possible in mysql

Comment: @Mr Blue Include Sample data and desire output.  Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM   tbl_users
JOIN   tbl_products 
  ON   userID = creatorID
WHERE  ( userid = 8 
         AND serialnumber = 23432535 ) 
        OR userid = 8
```